# Expand a command inside another command

Tags: expansion

I continue forth with my saga to expand stuff in LaTeX using `etoolbox`.

This time I have the following piece of code.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcount\infoCounter

\newcommand{\addInfoRef}[1]{
\unexpanded{\nameref{\csuse{info#1Label}}}
\cseappto{info#1Ref}{Mentioned in %
                    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{\nameref}}{\csuse{info\currentname Label}}%
                    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{\\}}
                    }
}


\newcommand{\newInfon}[3][]{
\listxadd\listInfo{#2}
\edef\currentname{#2}
\csedef{info#2Label}{infoKey\the\infoCounter}
\advance\infoCounter by 1
\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\csedef{info#2Img}{#1}}
\csedef{info#2Cnt}{#3}
\nullfont#3\normalfont
}

\newcommand{\printInfo}[1]{%
\edef\currentName{#1}
\section{#1}\label{\expandafter\csuse{info#1Label}}%
\csuse{info#1Cnt}
\ifcsname info#1Ref\endcsname
\\\begin{tabular}{p{9cm}}
  \csuse{info#1Ref}
\end{tabular}
\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Tests Result}

\newInfon{Test Case 1}{%
The result was inconclusive.}

\newInfon{Test Case 2}{%
The result was more conclusive than in \addInfoRef{Test Case 1}, but was still inconclusive.}

\newInfon{Test Case 3}{%
The result less conclusive than in \addInfoRef{Test Case 2}, but was still more conclusive than in \addInfoRef{Test Case 1}.}

\printInfo{Test Case 1}
\printInfo{Test Case 2}
\printInfo{Test Case 3}

\end{document}
```

The desired output is... well, ALMOST what is generated:

[image]

The two red dots atop show that something is being referenced before the time. If you try reordering `\printInfo{Test Case X}` and you'll notice that then the "Mentions" are not printed properly anymore. For instance, if I reorder:

```
\printInfo{Test Case 3}
\printInfo{Test Case 2}
\printInfo{Test Case 1}
```

I get

[image]

That is, some "Mention" entries are duplicated! I've considering doing something like

```
\ifcsname info\currentname#2Switch\endcsname{\relax}{%
  \cseappto{info#2Ref}{Mentioned in...}
}
\csedef{info\currentname#2Switch}{1}
```

in `\addInfoRef`, but that didn't work and I couldn't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do here actually. Besides that you're missing several `%` at the end of the opening `{` bracket of the code section of your commands.

Comment: Added more images to make it clearer.
In any case, I don't think that the % have anything to do with the fact that the expansion is not being done the way I would like it to be.

Comment: @Benedict they don't but they tend to add unwanted spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.
This is not my real code, this is just a simplified version I am posting here.

Comment: @Benedict: The comment about the `%` was an extra gift, because that's why I wrote `besides` ;-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation with `expl3` (via `xparse`). The `\newInfon` command has an optional argument to be used if the first mandatory argument contains non ASCII characters (I made an example): the optional argument is just a key to be used wherever a reference to the case is made.

The trick is to make `\addInfoRef` do two different things and to execute it when `\newInfon` is performed inside a box, so the output is eventually discarded.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\textgreek\relax}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_benedict_info_items_prop
\bool_new:N \l_benedict_info_add_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\newInfon}{O{#2}mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_benedict_info_items_prop
   { #1 key }  % key
   { #2 }
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_benedict_info_items_prop
   { #1 text } % text
   { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #3 } }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__benedict_info_temp_tl { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l_benedict_info_add_bool #3
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addInfoRef}{m}
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_benedict_info_add_bool
   {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g_benedict_info_#1_seq }
     {
      \seq_new:c { g_benedict_info_#1_seq }
     }
    \seq_gput_right:cx { g_benedict_info_#1_seq }
     {
      Mentioned ~ in ~ \exp_not:N \nameref{\l__benedict_info_temp_tl label}
     }
   }
   {
    \prop_item:Nn \g_benedict_info_items_prop { #1 key }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printInfo}{m}
 {
  \exp_args:Nx \section {\prop_item:Nn \g_benedict_info_items_prop { #1 key }}\label{#1label}
  \prop_item:Nn \g_benedict_info_items_prop { #1 text }
  \seq_if_exist:cT { g_benedict_info_#1_seq }
   {
    \\*[\medskipamount]
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{9cm} @{}}
    \seq_use:cn { g_benedict_info_#1_seq } { \\ }
    \end{tabular}
    \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Tests Result}

\newInfon[TC1]{Test Case (\textgreek{δοκιμή}) 1}{
  The result was inconclusive.
}

\newInfon{Test Case 2}{
  The result was more conclusive than in \addInfoRef{TC1},
  but was still inconclusive.
}

\newInfon{Test Case 3}{
  The result less conclusive than in \addInfoRef{Test Case 2},
  but was still more conclusive than in \addInfoRef{TC1}.
}

\printInfo{TC1}
\printInfo{Test Case 2}
\printInfo{Test Case 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woa, it works even with greek characters! However, expl3 notation is a total mystery to me, I cannot bring myself to comprehend it (at least yet). Moreover the rest of the package is written purely with etoolbox, so if I could stay there it would be better.

In any case, I've tried the box trick (more precisely with savebox), but went nowhere, or ended up with 2 copies of some of the "Mentions". Which lines of your code are responsible for this boxing?

Comment: @Benedict `\hbox_set:Nn` is the key you're looking for, but there's also the conditional in the definition of `\addInfoRef`.

Comment: Well, yeah, I have no idea how to your your solution, @egreg. My actual package is much more complicated than this (I just simplified it here to show the core of the problem) and I am completely oblivious to expl3 notation so I cannot translate it. 

Thank anyway. I will be waiting for a pure-etoolbox solution, or just give up LaTeX all together since debugging it is close to impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question through extensive trial-and-error. Basically I've created a `printingInfo` variable, set it to 0, and only set it to 1 during printInfo. Then the addInfoRef function only performs the cseappto if this printingInfo=0.

This is the working solution:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcount\infoCounter

\edef\printingInfo{0}%
\newcommand{\addInfoRef}[1]{%
\ifstrequal{\printingInfo}{0}{\unexpanded{\nameref{\csuse{info#1Label}}}}{%
\cseappto{info#1Ref}{Mentioned in %
\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\nameref}}{\csuse{info\currentname Label}}%
\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\\}}}%
}%
}


\newcommand{\newInfon}[3][]{
\edef\printingInfo{0}%
\edef\currentname{#2}
\csedef{info#2Label}{infoKey\the\infoCounter}
\advance\infoCounter by 1
\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\csedef{info#2Img}{#1}}
\csedef{info#2Cnt}{#3}
\nullfont#3\normalfont
}

\newcommand{\printInfo}[1]{%
\edef\printingInfo{1}%
\edef\currentname{#1}
\section{#1}\label{\expandafter\csuse{info#1Label}}%
\csuse{info#1Cnt}
\ifcsname info#1Ref\endcsname
\\\begin{tabular}{p{9cm}}
  \csuse{info#1Ref}
\end{tabular}
\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Tests Result}

\newInfon{Test Case 1}{%
The result was inconclusive.}

\newInfon{Test Case 2}{%
The result was more conclusive than in \addInfoRef{Test Case 1}, but was still inconclusive.}

\newInfon{Test Case 3}{%
The result less conclusive than in \addInfoRef{Test Case 2}, but was still more conclusive than in \addInfoRef{Test Case 1}.}

\printInfo{Test Case 1}
\printInfo{Test Case 2}
\printInfo{Test Case 3}

\end{document}
```

The only remaining problem now is the leftover spacing in-between "chapter 1" and the sections.