# Suppressing Output

Tags: fonts

This may sound bizarre, but I'm trying to write something and get LaTeX to *not* print it in the document (it arose from another question I had, [namely this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365128/expand-a-command-inside-another-command))

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\let\oldpar\par%
\let\par\relax%
\nullfont

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \emph{consectetur adipiscing elit} 2000$^\circ$C.

\[ ax^2 = b \left( \frac{\sqrt{t}}{42} \right)\]

\normalfont%
\let\par\oldpar%

\end{document}
```

If you compile this, you'll get a document where only maths mode and `\emph` are printed. The expected result would be to get nothing printed at all.

I am guessing that this happens because `\emph` and mathmode do not use `\normalfont` but some other font instead.

What would be the commands being used there? I've tried
`\let\itshape\relax`
but that didn't do any good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could add `\let\selectfont\relax` so no fonts will be selected via latex mechanisms, but I would not define `\par` to be relax (that will almost certainly end in tex spinning in an infinite loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the contents you want to hide in a box and output an empty box with the same size in the document.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
ABC
\setbox0=\vbox{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \emph{consectetur adipiscing elit} 2000$^\circ$C.

\[ ax^2 = b \left( \frac{\sqrt{t}}{42} \right)\]
}\par\vbox to \dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax{}
DEF
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution answers my question but doesn't solve my problem at all.
You see, inside my vbox there are lots of commands being called, which basically save things inside of variables for later use.

Those commands are, however, being ignored, and the variables remain empty. So I guess I'll need to keep on using \nullfont.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested redefintions are not very safe.

This document would loop forever and never terminate

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\let\oldpar\par%
\let\par\relax%
\nullfont

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \emph{consectetur adipiscing elit} 2000$^\circ$C.

\[ ax^2 = b \left( \frac{\sqrt{t}}{42} \right)\]

a\hrule

\normalfont%
\let\par\oldpar%

\end{document}
```